# how to seamlessly integrate subversion and git?

Tags: svn, git, deployment, branch

I'm looking for tips on how to seamlessly integrate subversion and git, for deploying web sites by a small team of web developers. We each have our own development versions of our sites on our local machines. We also have dev, staging, and live servers.

As our team has grown, we haven't updated our revision control and deployment strategies accordingly. We had all been checking into the trunk of a shared Subversion repository. Both the dev & staging servers ran from a checkout of the trunk, so updating them involved running "svn update" while the live server ran as an export from trunk which required an "svn export" to get the latest code. In either case, we would often update just certain files by updating or exporting just those files or directories. That worked okay when there was just one or two developers. However, a big downside was that we couldn't point to an individual tag that represented what was currently on live at any given time.

In keeping with corporate policy, we'd like to continue to use Subversion to store what we're now calling our "production branch," which will be what goes onto staging and live. However, we would like to use Git on our local and development sites. We especially like the idea of easier merges and being able to "cherry pick" updates that need to go live. We had initially planned on using git-svn, but it doesn't seem to work well in a shared environment such as our dev or staging servers.

Anyone else doing something like this? What's the best way to make it work? Or are we making it more difficult than it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derick Bailey has some good ways of doing this:

http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/derickbailey/archive/2010/02/03/branch-per-feature-how-i-manage-subversion-with-git-branches.aspx